# size of a list using pointer in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers

How to get size of a list using pointer ? I have the following piece of code. I put few integers inside and later, tried to get the size of the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main ()

{


list<int>* t;

for (int i=1; i<10; ++i)
{
    t->push_back(i*10);


}

cout<<"size:\t"<<t->size()<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happened next?

Comment: What's wrong with the code? That should work... Though you need to initialize the list!

Comment: You need to make `t` point to a valid list object. Note that this does not mean you *have* to use `new` as suggested in some answers. In fact, you should avoid `new` if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to initialise the pointer to actually point somewhere. That could be a dynamically-allocated list using `new` (in which case you should be using a smart pointer of some description), or it could be some other object that already exists (in which case this is "point"less, isn't it?).

Better yet, *don't use a pointer*:

```
list<int> l;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    l.push_back(i*10);
cout << "size:\t" << l.size() << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question in the Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't allocated `t`. Write `list<int>* t = new list<int>;` or better `unique_ptr<list<int>> t (new list<int>);` if you are in c++11 . But in this case allocating list on the stack will work better anyway.